How to determine minimum sampling rate when discretizing a transfer function?
When discretizing a first order low pass filter,
$$H(s)=\frac{\omega_c}{s+\omega_c}$$
it is required that the sampling rate be at least twice the cutoff frequency.
Now given an arbitrary transfer function (like a controller for a plant or a filter for a sensor), how do I determine the minimum sampling rate when discretizing it? This is needed to know whether the transfer function is realizable in real hardware.
My guess is to find the bandwidth $\omega_b$ of the transfer function from a bode plot and apply:
$$\frac{\omega_b}{2\pi}<\frac{1}{2}f_{sampling}$$
Is this correct?

Yes.
Although, for practical systems, it is better to keep the sampling frequency 5 or 10 times (rather than just 2 times) the maximum frequency of interest.
